# How to bisect an arc using only the compass

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

The [Mohr-Mascheroni Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Mascheroni_theorem) (and also [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass.shtml)) states that any geometric construction that can be performed by a compass and straightedge can be performed by a compass alone.

A key point in the proof of this theorem is the bisection of a given arc with compass alone.

How to achieve this is explained  [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass7.shtml).

The proof heavily depends on the Pythagorean Theorem.

I am interested in a proof, if any, of this key point which avoids the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: Interesting! You need just by a compass, to construct a straight edge for example. To do so you have to prove that you will be able to produce infinitely many points that are in the same line of a given pair of points $A, B$.

Comment: @NotaChoice - The actual theorem states that any points or circles constructible by compass and straight-edge can be constructed with compass alone. For lines, all you can do is construct the points that would have allowed you to construct the line if you had a straight-edge.